# Send an HTTP request with a ESP8266 and Arduino

Tags: http, arduino, esp8266

Please forgive the total noob question.

If I type the following string into the address bar of a web browser and hit enter, it adds the two data points to a bucket in Initial State:

> http://insecure-groker.initialstate.com/api/events?accessKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&bucketKey=YYYYYYYYYYYY&Temp=275&dTdt=2

I want to use the esp8266 connected to an arduino to do this programatically. I have the ESP wired correctly and I can successfully connect it to my router. But once connected, I am not sure the AT commands to send it to get it to send the above string to the website.

```
#define ESP8266 Serial2 //use serial2 to esp8266

void setup() {
        ESP8266.begin(9600); //initialise the 8266 at 9600

        ESP8266.println("AT+RST"); // reset the 8266

        ESP8266.println("AT+CWJAP=\"MySSID\",\"MyPassword\""); // connect to router

        delay(5000);

        ESP8266.println("AT+CIPMUX=0"); // enable single connection 

        ESP8266.println("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"insecure-groker.initialstate.com\",80");

}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to find your answer in this post here:

https://github.com/initialstate/arduino_streamers/blob/master/arduinowifishieldstream.ino#L184

I've highlighted the beginning of the `postData` method that builds the event request and then writes the HTTP command to serial.

One difference is that this example is using a JSON body instead of url params like your example.